# Complaint Against Visit Visa Refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

We were refused a visit visa last month of 6 month. 
We complained against the decision through MP and some email adresses. 
We were asked to submit 3 more documents.
Today we were asked to resubmit our passport today at VAC.
Does that indicate an approval or still refusal ?

Comment: Looks like an approval. Why else would they ask for resubmission? Do let us know the email addresses you sent the complaints to for our benefit.

Comment: Good luck. Do let us know the final outcome.

Comment: If you get a visa and do update here, would you be willing to tell us the nature of your complaint? As in, was it a technical mistake on the part of the decision (incorrect maths, misreading of something you've said) or just a disagreement about their final subjective decision?

Comment: Hi @WorldWillEnd, will appreciate you collating the comments above and and updates when you got your passport with visa back. It will be a valuable piece of knowledge to have!

Answer (score 2):

Applied Family Visit Visa in 2018. Refused after 3 weeks. Complained against the decision within 1 week.After 3 weeks were asked to submit further documents on email and then resubmit passport and got the passport back after further 2 weeks.  Application to Refusal to Complaint and Approval all within complete 2 months.

The complaint procedure is listed on the following GOV.UK page 
https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration/about/complaints-procedure
and at the same time the sponsor or relative in UK can complain to their respective MP. Following both steps at the same time gave us a favourable result.

Comment: What was the basis of your complaint?

Comment: The paper that they considered non authentic or non verfiable was a true paper of of government of my country , and it was verifiable as well.